# Generate PDF/html report and send report as mail in SonarQube 6.0

Tags: email, pdf, reporting

Currently I am using Sonarqube 6.0. I need to generate PDF/HTML report and send report as mail to Users.I have successfully set up the email configuration in the SonarQube and test send mail has worked correctly. 
I tried using Report plugin and Governor plugin, but it is not compatible with SonarQube 6.0.

Is there any other way to generate PDF/HTML reports in SonarQube 6.0?

Comment: Me too looking for the same.